# What would be the angular.js equivalent of this jquery code? (submit a hidden form)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on a project that uses Angular.js and not JQuery.

I want to submit data via POST with a hidden form. Normally I would do this with something like this:

`$('<form method="post" action="url">
        <input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="event_id">
        <input type="hidden" name="text" value="text">
      </form>').submit();`

How could I do this with Angular.js?

Comment: Are you trying to use a hidden form (of which I can't think of a use case) or to make a `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make an ajax request.  You would probably do this with jQuery too instead of submitting a "hidden" form unless you wanted to force a page reload which is likely undesirable.

```
$http.post("url", {event_id: "event_id", text: "text"})
```